# Genus of a pair of pants

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I think I might be confused about what a pair of pants is...but I see it as a 2 sphere with three holes. Or a disk with two disks removed.
I don't understand why its genus is zero...
Why not three?
This surface has boundary, is there a special definition for the genus in such cases?What motivates it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a definition for surfaces with boundary, not to be confused with say, a two torus?

Comment: Usually, a pair of pants is a $2$-dimensional manifold with three boundary components. It is *not* homeomorphic to a torus of any dimension. But I don't see what the $3$-sphere thing should do. Can you describe what you mean by "to use a $3$-sphere"?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mess!What I meant was that the 2 sphere with 3 holes could be stretched to get a two disk, with two removed disks .

Comment: (that is, a pair of pants)

Comment: Indeed, a sphere with $3$ holes is homeomorphic to a (open) disk with two holes. And your questions is what the genus of such a pair of pants is? How do you define "genus" (you probably want to edit your question and add the definitions)?

Comment: On the other hand, if the pants are made of fabric with nonzero thickness, then the _surface_ of the pants has genus 2.

Comment: @HenningMakholm well, "pair of pants" has a fixed meaning in topology. +1 anyway

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a sphere with three disks removed is a pair of pants. A disk with two disks removed is also a pair of pants. That is correct.

You might be confused because you may think the genus is the number of "holes" in a surface. But it's not the same kind of hole we are talking about. The hole in a torus isn't something that was removed from the surface. It's a feature of the topology. We "see" it when we view the torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it's not really... there. The notion of "hole" isn't well-defined, so it's best to think about other definitions of the genus.

A first definition of the genus of a surface is the maximum number of non-self-intersecting closed curves that you can draw on a surface without disconnecting it. You cannot draw a closed curve on a pair of pants without disconnecting it (try to do it), so the genus is zero.

Another definition is more algebraic and works for orientable surfaces. Let $\chi$ be the Euler characteristic, $g$ be the genus, and $b$ the number of boundary components. Then $\chi = 2 - 2g - b$. The pair of pants clearly has $b = 3$. It is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of two circles, $S^1 \vee S^1$, so the Euler characteristic is $1-2=-1$. Plug that in, you get $-1 = 2-2g-3$ so $g = 0$ again.

Comment: You cant draw a closed curve on a pair of pants? How about around the leg? Or around the waist?

Comment: @clathratus I wrote "You cannot draw a closed curve on a pair of pants **without disconnecting it**".

Comment: I guess I am confused on the meaning of that statement. What do you mean when you say "without disconnecting it"?

Comment: I mean that there does not exist a closed curve $\gamma \subset P$ (where $P$ is the pair of pants) such that $P \setminus \gamma$ (the pair of pants with the curve removed) remains connected.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. That's very elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) gives a definition of genus for manifolds with boundary:

> Alternatively, it can be defined in terms of the Euler characteristic $\chi$, via the relationship $\chi = 2 − 2g$ for closed surfaces, where $g$ is the genus. For surfaces with $b$ boundary components, the equation reads $\chi = 2 − 2g − b$.

So if you want to calculate the genus of a pair of pants, calculate the Euler characteristic first. This is a triangulation of something homeomorphic to a pair of pants:
[image]

I count 19 vertices, 40 edges and 20 triangles. So we have Euler characteristic $\chi = 19-40+20 = -1$. Since we have $b=3$ boundary components, we obtain
$$-1 = 2-2g-3 \Leftrightarrow g=0$$

Comment: Why did you include the extra triangles on the boundary? You could have gotten away with just 8 triangles (the ones bordering the holes). Then $\chi = 13 - 22 + 8 = -1$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I was not sure what definition of triangulation the OP knew and I wanted something homeomorphic. Having to count is just a bit of inconvenience.